# where to put method that works on a model

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django.

I have a model called Agrument.  Arguments have sides and owners.  I have a function that returns back the side of the most recent argument of a certain user.

like  obj.get_current_side(username)

I've added this to the actual Argument model like this

```
 def get_current_side(self, user):
        return self.argument_set.latest('pub_date').side
```

I am starting to think this doesn't make sense because there may not be an instance of an Argument.  Is this a place I would use a class method?  I thought about making a util class, but I'm thinking that it makes sense to be associated with the Argument class.

Answer (score 2):

It would make more sense to have instance methods on the `User` model:

```
def get_current_side(self):
    try:
        return self.arguments.latest('pub_date').side
    except User.DoesNotExist, e:
        return None
```

You can do this by extending the `User` model as explained here:

- [Extending the Django User model with inheritance](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/)

*Edit: I'm not exactly sure which exception gets thrown.*

Answer (score 1):

This should be a method on a custom model manager:

```
# in models.py
class ArgumentManager(models.manager.Manager):
    def get_current_side(self, user):
        try:
            return self.filter(user=user).latest('pub_date').side
        except Argument.DoesNotExist:
            return None

class Argument(models.Model):
    # fields etc...

    objects = ArgumentManager()


# Calling:

side = Argument.objects.get_current_side(user)
```

Alternaticely you **can** extend `contrib.auth.user` and add `get_current_size()` on it. But I wouldn't mess with it until I'm very confident with Django.

BTW: Most of the code in this page is wrong; for example `user` variable is not used at all on the OP's snipplet.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are model managers.

[Django docs on managers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#topics-db-managers) with managers you can add a function to the model class instead of a model instance.